# Exit loop with KeyboardInterrupt then begin another loop in python

Tags: python, loops, sockets, break

I currently have a piece of code designed to communicate with two motors via a TCP Device Server which sends ASCII commands to them in order to trace sinusoidal paths. I wish to have the movement continue indefinitely and then immediately stop when `KeyboardInterrupt` is triggered, then have the motors move back to their defined home positions before the program ends.

This code can currently replicate sinusodial motion, but it currently does not stop immediately when `KeyboardInterrupt` is triggered, nor do the motors move back to their home positions. The sinusodial loop is designed such that when `KeyboardInterrupt` occurs, a global variable called `move` changes from True to False and this breaks the loop. The simplified code is given below:

```
import socket
import time
import numpy as np
import math

pi = math.pi

try:
    s1 = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) #TCP Server Connection
    s2 = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
except:
    print("Failed to connect")
    exit()
print("Sockets Created")

s1.connect(("192.168.177.200", 4001)) # Y motor
s2.connect(("192.168.177.200", 4002)) # X motor

# Disengage the motor to allow manual movement by wheel
s1.send("DI\n".encode("ASCII")) 
message = s1.recv(1024).decode()
s2.send("DI\n".encode("ASCII"))
message = s1.recv(1024).decode()



homeposition = input("Are the motors centred? Press 'y' to confirm: ")
if homeposition == 'y':
    s1.send("EN\n".encode("ASCII"))
    s2.send("EN\n".encode("ASCII")) # energise the motors so they cannot be moved
    print("Motors Engaged")
    s1.send("HO\n".encode("ASCII")) # set current position as home position
    s2.send("HO\n".encode("ASCII")) # set current position as home position
else:
    print("Set home position and restart program")
    exit()


#----ADD DATA FOR SAMPLING SINUSODIAL FUNCTIONS----

radius = input("Desired radius of movement (mm):")
radius = float(radius)
print("radius of circular path (mm): ", radius)

# need slightly different ratios for each motor due to different thread sizes
gearpositionlim_x = 20000 #one rotation equals 2.5mm (+ bearing ration on manipulator of 2:1)
gearpositionlim_y = 10000 #one rotation equals 2mm



# sample sine and cosine
step = 2*pi / 1000
time_range = np.arange(0,2*pi + step,step)
x_motorrange = gearpositionlim_x*np.cos(time_range)
y_motorrange = gearpositionlim_y*np.sin(time_range)
x_motorrange = ['la'+str(int(i)) for i in x_motorrange]
y_motorrange = ['la'+str(int(i)) for i in y_motorrange]
#print(x_motorrange)

x_motorrange_wcom = []
y_motorrange_wcom = []
{x_motorrange_wcom.extend([e, 'm', 'np']) for e in x_motorrange} # add movement prompts and wait for movement to complete
{y_motorrange_wcom.extend([e, 'm', 'np']) for e in y_motorrange} # add movement prompts and wait for movement to complete

# Set Acceleration and Deceleration of Motors
s1.send("AC10\n".encode("ASCII"))
message = s1.recv(1024).decode()
s2.send("AC10\n".encode("ASCII"))
message = s2.recv(1024).decode()
print("Acceleration set to 10 ") 

s1.send("DEC10\n".encode("ASCII"))
message = s1.recv(1024).decode()
s2.send("DEC10\n".encode("ASCII"))
message = s2.recv(1024).decode()
print("Deceleration set to 10")

def setup():  #move to initial position before starting movement
    s2.send(str(str(x_motorrange_wcom[0])+"\n").encode("ASCII"))
    s2.send("m\n".encode("ASCII"))
    s2.send("np\n".encode("ASCII"))
    s2.send("delay200\n".encode("ASCII"))
    
def end():
    print("Movement ended, return to home position")
    s1.send("la0\n".encode("ASCII"))
    s1.send("m\n".encode("ASCII"))
    s1.send("np\n".encode("ASCII"))
    s1.send("delay200\n".encode("ASCII"))
    s1.send("DI\n".encode("ASCII"))
    s1.send("delay200\n".encode("ASCII"))
    time.sleep(2)
    s2.send("la0\n".encode("ASCII"))
    s2.send("m\n".encode("ASCII"))
    s2.send("np\n".encode("ASCII"))
    s2.send("delay200\n".encode("ASCII"))
    s2.send("DI\n".encode("ASCII"))
    s2.send("delay200\n".encode("ASCII"))


def motormove():
    global move
    try:
        for i in np.arange(0,len(x_motorrange)):
            if (move == True):
                s1.send(str(str(x_motorrange[i])+"\n").encode("ASCII"))
                s2.send(str(str(y_motorrange[i])+"\n").encode("ASCII"))
            else:
                break
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        move = False
        print(move)
        end()
            

#-------------------------------------------
setup()
name = input("Code Ready, press enter to proceed: ")
if name == "":
        print("Code Running: Press ctrl + c to end")
        while (move == True):
            motormove()
```

I believe my issue is with my function `motormove()`, but I am unsure of what I should do in order to achieve my desired operation. Does anyone know how this can be achieved?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Using library **signal** should be sufficient for your usecase. See code bellow.

```
import socket
import signal
import time
import numpy as np
import math

pi = math.pi
try:
    s1 = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) #TCP Server Connection
    s2 = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
except:
    print("Failed to connect")
    exit()
print("Sockets Created")

s1.send("HO\n".encode("ASCII")) # set current position as home position
s2.send("HO\n".encode("ASCII")) # set current position as home position

gearpositionlim = int(10000)
# sample sine and cosine
step = 2*pi / 2000
time_range = np.arange(0,2*pi + step,step)
x_motorrange = gearpositionlim*np.sin(time_range)
y_motorrange = gearpositionlim*np.cos(time_range)

def handler(signum, frame):
    res = input("Ctrl-c was pressed. Do you really want to exit? y/n ")
    if res == 'y':
        exit(1) 
    else:
        #Do STH


def setup():
    s2.send(y_motorrange[0])+"\n").encode("ASCII"))
    s2.send("m\n".encode("ASCII"))
    s2.send("np\n".encode("ASCII"))
    s2.send("delay200\n".encode("ASCII"))

def end():
    print("Movement ended, return to home position")
    s1.send("la0\n".encode("ASCII"))
    s1.send("m\n".encode("ASCII"))
    s1.send("np\n".encode("ASCII"))
    s1.send("delay200\n".encode("ASCII"))
    s1.send("DI\n".encode("ASCII"))
    s1.send("delay200\n".encode("ASCII"))
    time.sleep(2)
    s2.send("la0\n".encode("ASCII"))
    s2.send("m\n".encode("ASCII"))
    s2.send("np\n".encode("ASCII"))
    s2.send("delay200\n".encode("ASCII"))
    s2.send("DI\n".encode("ASCII"))
    s2.send("delay200\n".encode("ASCII"))


def motormove():
    global move
    try:
        for i in np.arange(0,len(x_motorrange)):
            if (move == True):
                s1.send(str(str(x_motorrange[i])+"\n").encode("ASCII"))
                s2.send(str(str(y_motorrange[i])+"\n").encode("ASCII"))
            else:
                break
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, handler)

            

#-------------------------------------------
setup()
name = input("Code Ready, press enter to proceed: ")
if name == "":
        print("Code Running: Press ctrl + c to end")
        while (move == True):
            motormove()
```

This should be working just fine, note the signal function being called on **KeyboardInterrupt**, this redirects to signal function where, you can either exit or do something else.